# How to fit points using fft

Tags: discrete-mathematics, fast-fourier-transform

Say I got a data of several points, for example:

```
[  6.32308617   5.33624905   0.46463384   2.70682874  18.76600741
  14.37138067   1.89334222  12.20420302  15.22460287   6.16349825]
```

Assume they are Y coordinates, and the corresponding X coordinates are:`[0 1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9]` plot them would be like that: [Plot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/0IEIY.png)

Then I did a fft to the former data(which I assumed represents Y) using the `fft()` function in python numpy, which give me the list of complex number below:

```
[ 83.45383224 +0.00000000e+00j -15.21808989 +1.36388455e+01j
   5.87603709 +1.99268945e+01j  -5.84740275 -2.95182061e+01j
   4.13321389 +5.39872362e+00j   1.88951278 -3.37507799e-14j
   4.13321389 -5.39872362e+00j  -5.84740275 +2.95182061e+01j
   5.87603709 -1.99268945e+01j -15.21808989 -1.36388455e+01j]
```

And I want to generate a formula to fit the points. I thought these complex number represents $C_n$ in :

$s(x)=\sum_{n=-\infty}^{+\infty}C_ne^i$

but what is $i$ ? How can I construct a formula that could fit the plot? If that complex form is difficult to explain, how about a triangle form?

P.S. the purpose of the question is not to fit curve or something, but to generate formula through discrete data, I thought fft should be the way to do that

Comment: **Why** are you using fft?  I don't see how going from a list of real numbers to a list of complex numbers helps.

Comment: @user247327 Actually I'm posting a simplified question here... The complete one got a large amount of data, and I can't get a good result when using regression. So I thought fft may works

Comment: Do you know what fft is supposed to do?

Comment: What are the points, in what sense should they be fitted, why the tag discrete mathematics ?

Comment: @Batman yeah, but I'm more familiar with the triangle form, not the complex one. I'm bad at things exponential...

Comment: @mathreadler The complete points set is a collection of a picture's edge,
 my target is from [here](http://blog.wolfram.com/2013/05/17/making-formulas-for-everything-from-pi-to-the-pink-panther-to-sir-isaac-newton/), the last step, which is to generate the formula.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is 
$s(x)=\sum_{n=-\infty}^{+\infty}C_n e^{2i\pi nf_0x}$ with on your case : $f_0$ is $1/10$ (10 is the total length of the signal in your time unit).

FTT function gives $n*[C_0, C_1, C_2, C_3, C_4, C_5+C_{-5}, C_{-4}, C_{-3}, C_{-2}, C_{-1} ]$ Where n=10 (number of sample).

To compute it, you have to add zeros on your coefficients. As example, in Matlab :

```
Y=fft(y); 
Y2=[Y(1:5) Y(6)/2 zeros(1,9) Y(6)/2 Y(7:end)]*2; 
y2=ifft(Y2); 
plot(0:9,y,0:.5:9.5,y2)
```

Comment: Is $f_0$ a constant in that case?

Comment: yes, it is 1/length of signal (in time unit, (not in sample))